# processing and downloading JSON files into specific folders

Tags: r, purrr

I have some data which looks like:

```
  index                                                                                                                          title
1 2.1.1                                                                                           Indicadores de renta media y mediana
2 2.1.2                                                                                            Distribución por fuente de ingresos
3 2.1.3                  Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo
4 2.1.4 Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad
5 2.1.5   Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad
6 2.1.6       Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo/encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo
                                             link provincia                            provincesFolderLocations
1 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30656&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
2 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30813&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
3 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30657&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
4 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30659&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
5 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30660&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
6 https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30661&L=0  Albacete /home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete
                                                          json_link
1 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30656?tip=AM&
2 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30813?tip=AM&
3 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30657?tip=AM&
4 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30659?tip=AM&
5 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30660?tip=AM&
6 https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30661?tip=AM&
```

I am trying to `map` over two of the columns using `map2`. I want to go to the link in the column `json_link` and use `fromJSON` from the `jsonlite` package to read the JSON file. Then I want to save that file into the location specified in the column `provincesFolderLocations`.

I am thinking of something similar to the following (which doesn't work):

```
downloadAndStoreJSONData <- function(jsonLink, provinceFolderLoc){
 JSON_in = fromJSON(jsonLink)
 JSON_out = write_json(JSON_in)
}

DATA %>% 
  map2(json_link, provincesFolderLocations, ~downloadAndStoreJSONData(.x, .y))
```

Additionally, instead of just saving the JSON data it collects I want to `bind_cols` to the `DATA` so I keep all of the information. Then I want to save this final data frame as the JSON file.

Data:

```
    DATA <- structure(list(index = c("2.1.1", "2.1.2", "2.1.3", "2.1.4", 
"2.1.5", "2.1.6"), title = c("Indicadores de renta media y mediana", 
"Distribución por fuente de ingresos", "Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y tramos de edad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo de determinados umbrales fijos por sexo y nacionalidad", 
"Porcentaje de población con ingresos por unidad de consumo por debajo/encima de determinados umbrales relativos por sexo"
), link = c("https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30656&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30813&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30657&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30659&L=0", "https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30660&L=0", 
"https://www.ine.es/jaxiT3/Tabla.htm?t=30661&L=0"), provincia = c("Albacete", 
"Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete", "Albacete"), 
    provincesFolderLocations = c("/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
    "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
    "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete", 
    "/home/bscuser/Escritorio/mobility/data/INE/Albacete"), json_link = c("https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30656?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30813?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30657?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30659?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30660?tip=AM&", 
    "https://servicios.ine.es/wstempus/js/es/DATOS_TABLA/30661?tip=AM&"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I can get a single JSON file using:

(Each observations takes about a minute to collect)

THen bind the columns to gether.

```
jsonLINK <- DATA$json_link[4]
JSONin <- fromJSON(jsonLINK)
DATA_Final <- bind_cols(JSONin, DATA[4, ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a location to write the data in `write_json` -

```
downloadAndStoreJSONData <- function(jsonLink, provinceFolderLoc){
  JSON_in = fromJSON(jsonLink)
  write_json(JSON_in, paste0(sub('\\?.*', '', basename(jsonLink)), '.json'))
}

purrr::map2(DATA$json_link, DATA$provincesFolderLocations, downloadAndStoreJSONData)
```

where `paste0` creates the filenames of the json file to save.

```
paste0(sub('\\?.*', '', basename(DATA$json_link)), '.json')
#[1] "30656.json" "30813.json" "30657.json" "30659.json" "30660.json" "30661.json"
```